# Code-correctness in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-policy, off-topic, help-center

As pointed by the poster of this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8609/dynamic-programming-algorithm-code-review, our FAQ states the following is on-topic:

- Code correctness

However, on the basis of various past questions on Meta the policy is clearly that non-working is off-topic for this site.

I think the intention of the FAQ is to say that pointing out flaws in the logic that the poster has missed is on-topic, but posters asking people to find their logical flaws is not on-topic. But I think the FAQ could use some clarification on this point.

Comment: I agree; it'd be a good idea to be explicit about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proposed new wording changes in bold:

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are
>   working on for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a
>   specific **working** piece of code from your project in the following
>   areas…
>
> 1. Best practices and design pattern usage
> 2. Security issues
> 3. Performance
> 4. **Correctness in unanticipated cases**