# Is asking for correctness check on-topic or not?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, close-reasons, specific-question

As per [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/correctness-in-the-faq) and [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/how-to-deal-with-code-asking-is-this-correct-when-it-is-in-fact-correct) question on meta, asking about correctness is on-topic yet [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/a-program-that-deliberately-makes-mistakes) was closed. The comment given was:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing the code to figure out if the given problem is solved and not about improving code quality

The comment got upvoted four times (probably by one or more of the close voters).

While I agree that it's no a really great question, I would have thought that it is still on-topic, isn't it?

Comment: BTW, I believe the comment gets upvoted automatically when you vote to close and select that comments as the reason.

Comment: @svick I can verify that. Just tested it on one of the many questions in the StackOverflow close queue.

Comment: Well then *that's* how one gets [badge:pundit]!! And I thought it was a luck badge...

Comment: @retailcoder: I thought people "earned" it by being snarky...

Comment: @Jamal me too, but being first to suggest a custom close reason and then having that auto-comment auto-upvoted by 4 people that think you're right about it makes it a bit easier no?

Comment: @retailcoder: True.  But, you would still need a 5th person to upvote it.  I've hardly seen that happen.

Comment: @Jamal It's easier if your custom close reason is snarky :)

Comment: @retailcoder: Well, when I become a moderator, I may need to keep that at a minimum.  Besides, SO provides much more opportunity to make such messages.

Comment: *This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be off-topic.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the question was of a low quality, in my opinion.  the OP needed to read the assignment and then look at the code.  the code satisfies the assignment.

this question is not Code Review.

No Offence, but the OP needs to have faith in themselves and their ability to follow directions (and read).

the OP is looking for confirmation that they did it right.  they should turn it in, if it is wrong the teacher will be able to tell them what they did wrong and teach them the right way to do it.

I know that we do review code from homework assignments, but this isn't an instance where we can review the code.

the question asks a `yes or no` question. which is covered in this FAQ

[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean >“anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. >What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - **inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”**
> - **tend to have long, not short, answers**
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

(*emphasis added by Malachi*)

Answer (score 6):

I was a bit unsure about this one at first, hence why I didn't vote on it.  However, after looking at it now, I can see why it was closed.

The OP was specifically asking if the solution followed the instructions.  That alone could imply that the code quality didn't matter (as mentioned in that comment).  Had the OP asked for both at least, then perhaps it would've stayed open.

Also, because it's homework, fulfilling that request would've resulted in "giving" the OP the answer.  I would assume that the instructor cares more about correctness than code quality.  Again, had the latter been requested, then it would've been okay to review.  But asking to make sure the assignment was done correctly is not in good spirit.